# Convert positive numbers and NaN to 1 and negative numbers to 0 in a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion, converters

I have a large csv file with a timestamp and a corresponding value. Is there an easy and convenient way to convert all the positive numbers (in column 1) and NaN to 1, and negative numbers to 0? I want to save the new dataframe to a new csv file. Example:
from:

```
                            0           1
0   2020-01-01 00:00:00+00:00      123.97
1   2020-01-01 00:04:00+00:00         NaN
2   2020-01-01 00:05:00+00:00      157.03
3   2020-01-01 00:06:00+00:00      184.82
4   2020-01-01 00:07:00+00:00     -197.36
```

to:

```
                            0           1
0   2020-01-01 00:00:00+00:00           1
1   2020-01-01 00:04:00+00:00           1
2   2020-01-01 00:05:00+00:00           1
3   2020-01-01 00:06:00+00:00           1
4   2020-01-01 00:07:00+00:00           0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think simpliest here is use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) for less like `0`:

```
df[1] = np.where(df[1].lt(0), 0, 1)
```

Or invert mask and convert to integers:

```
df[1] = (~df[1].lt(0)).astype(int)
```